# Sublime 2: Strange output using build system for Python Anaconda

Tags: python, sublimetext2, anaconda

I updated my Anaconda Python interpreter to 2.7.9 and some libraries as numpy, matplotlib and pandas in a mac with OS X 10.10.2. However, when I tried to run a script in sublime text 2, despite that the code runs, I am getting the following messages. Any idea how to fix it? Thank you.

```
sh: sysctl: command not found
sh: grep: command not found
sh: sw_vers: command not found
sh: grep: command not found
```

Comment: Are you running on Windows? It seems your script is looking for some linux tools.

Comment: This error looks like it is unrelated to Anaconda.